# how center a selected picture in the gallery?

Tags: android, gallery, center, image-gallery

how to center an image from gallery? If i use setSelection()
the gallery didn't are center, she move sometime in left sometime in right. 
She move in center only if the image was in extremities or if the selected image was in center.

If i do a second clique the picture go in center, i don't understand why. I use a setOnItemClickListener to change the image.

Comment: You will need to post some code. Describing what you are trying to do.

Comment: if i click of a image of the gallery, i change the image. of the gallery and a would like to center this gallery in the mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the behavior of the Gallery.Just Use the classes of the Gallery Customize it which involve CustomGallery CustomAbsSpinner and CustomAdapterView and change the function of Gallery class getCenterOfGallery() as per your requirement.